Question regarding "strategy of life" closed for being "opinion-based"
My question posted on Philosophy Stack Exchange was closed. I’m wondering why it was closed and how to modify it to make it suitable for the site. The reason shown there was that "This question is opinion-based". I do not understand it. From my understanding, philosophy itself is pretty much "opinion-based" instead of "fact-based", so I'll be pretty surprised if the site only accepts "technical questions" like StackOverflow. How can I improve the question?

Best to wait for a moderator to respond, but seeing previous meta questions over time on this issue . . . actually yes, Philosophy.SE is meant to be "technical" and "fact-based," which mandates that most questions on this site should be ones of scholarship (who argued X and why). If we allowed questions that are up for grabs, the reputation system ceases to be meaningful beyond "the users here like my opinions," which isn't the purpose of the SE sites (even if it does happen sometimes).

Worth reading: Should opinion-based questions always be allowed on the philosophy board?

I suggest (1) Delete your other meta question (2) On your main question put this meta question as a link in response to @JD suggestion-comment

SE does not ban all opinions.  Our posters are skilled experts in their various fields, and "what is the best way to do X" type questions actually call for opinion-based answers.  Here is one discussion from another Meta:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4235/primarily-opinion-based-questions-answers
BUT -- some questions have only a few answers, and others spawn an effective infinity of answers, while SE is designed to narrow answers down to one or a few best.
Your question is a "wisdom" question.  Most mature adults think they have attained wisdom, and will feel qualified to answer it, but the answers are likely to be all over the map, not just a few. The question is also of the form "this is what I think, what do "SE members think", which is a question form specifically cited as a bad form for this site.
Rephrasing your question to be "what do major schools of moral philosophy think of how we should address this issue" would limit the solicitation of poster's opinions,  and would likely improve the quality of answers you get.  It might still get closed, but the odds of closure would go down a lot with that kind of rephrasing.

I like the classification of "wisdom questions"--I think it might be a good addition to the what-to-ask helppage

Pursuing wisdom is one of the major goals of philosophy, and passing on accumulated wisdom from experts is one of the goals of Stack Exchange, so wisdom questions are not out of bounds at all.  The trouble is when there is a lot of diversity of opinion as to what is "wise", we get opinion-based discourse that does not converge.  Because of this, questions should not automatically be closed for asking for opinion based answers, but SOME such questions are disasters for an SE format.  Basically a question that converges on a few useful wisdom-based answers is good, the rest not.
